# how to display alert message box in sql server using stord procedure ,if condition not satisfied

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to display a message box in .net(front end) using stored procedure in sql server if conditon not satisfied. i wanted to write the condition in stored proc only to display the message box in front end.

Thanks in advance,
Venkat.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: So, You want, from within the stored procedure, to send a message to the front end application user? What does this front end application supposed to do then?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Write your stored procedure to return an appropriate value, according to the result, and make your .net front act on that result accordingly,

Answer (score 0):

You can make the stored procedure return something using OUTPUT parameter based on the query in the stored procedure..

BAsed on the OUT PUT value , you could display the message box

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the RAISERROR method on your Stored Procedure

Check this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321903